# Writing an audio file to websocket using IBM Watson Android sdk

Tags: android, websocket, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I realized after going through a post in the IBM developer forums that the android sdk reads bytes from the mic recording and writes them to the websocket. I am now trying to read bytes from an audio file on memory and write them to the websocket. How should I do this? So far I have:

```
public class AudioCaptureThread extends Thread{

private static final String TAG = "AudioCaptureThread";
private boolean mStop = false;
private boolean mStopped = false;
private int mSamplingRate = -1;
private IAudioConsumer mIAudioConsumer = null;

// the thread receives high priority because it needs to do real time audio capture
// THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO = "Standard priority of the most important audio threads"
public AudioCaptureThread(int iSamplingRate, IAudioConsumer IAudioConsumer) {
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    mSamplingRate = iSamplingRate;
    mIAudioConsumer = IAudioConsumer;
}

// once the thread is started it runs nonstop until it is stopped from the outside
@Override
public void run() {

    File path = Activity.getContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File (path, "whatstheweatherlike.wav");
    int length = (int) file.length();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    mIAudioConsumer.consume(bytes);
}
```

However, Activity.getContext is not recognized. I can convert the file to bytes in MainActivity but how do I then write it to the websocket? Am I on the right track or is this not the right way? If it is, how do I solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activity.getContext` is not recognized because there's no reference to `Activity`, since it's just a `Thread`. You would have to pass in the `Activity`, although it would likely make more sense just to pass in the `Context` if you need it.

You've got the right idea that you can create a `FileInputStream` and use that. You might like to use our `MicrophoneCaptureThread` as a reference. It'd be a very similar situation, except you'd be using your `FileInputStream` instead of reading from the microphone. You can check it out (and an example project that uses it) here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/android/library/audio/MicrophoneCaptureThread.java

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I was using the original AudioCaptureThread class from the android sdk (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk/blob/master/speech-android-wrapper/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/android/speech_to_text/v1/audio/AudioCaptureThread.java) as a reference. Passing the context as a parameter in the constructor did the work.